# Ride request detail API not giving all deatils

Tags: uber-api

My app is ready for production but request details API does not return complete data. I already whitelisted my ip from where i am sending ride request
i am using request endoint to find details with below URL

https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/3638f4e4-25d7-47f6-8743-9616d4b4a2df

when i send request using curl below response received form Uber

Array
(
    [status] => processing
    [destination] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 25.7616798
            [longitude] => -80.1917902
        )

```
[product_id] => 90384182-0269-4564-827d-e3c42c0eb83b
[request_id] => 3638f4e4-25d7-47f6-8743-9616d4b4a2df
[driver] => 
[pickup] => Array
    (
        [latitude] => 25.790654
        [longitude] => -80.1300455
    )

[eta] => 
[location] => 
[vehicle] => 
[surge_multiplier] => 1
[shared] => 1
```

)

Here driver details, eta everything is empty. I am using production account and i have complete access.

Answer (score 1):

The request details for a request with status `processing` will return null for eta, location, vehicle and driver because the status indicates that Uber tries to match your rider with a driver. As soon as they are matched, the request status changes to `accepted`. From this point in time, you will get all the details for the request. If you would like to test this behavior, please check out the Sandbox documentation [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sandbox). You can change the status of a request within the Sandbox by sending a `PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}`. As payload, it requires a JSON object with a status: `{"status": "accepted"}`.

Comment: My app is ready for Live environment, when i try to login on uber account with user that is not added under developers section in Uber API after login user get invalid_scope error.

Comment: Could you please open a new question with all the details? Like the URL you use to authenticate the users. Thanks!